# R, xgboost: eval_metric for count:poisson

Tags: r, xgboost

I wonder what are the recommended `eval_metric`s for `count:poisson` as objective in [xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md) in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from XGBOOST documents:
“poisson-nloglik”: negative log-likelihood for Poisson regression.

You might want to go and read more about poisson n loglikelihood.

Here is a link for you to get started:
https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/31

Hope this can be helpful